# Password and confirm not matching in react. I want to show error on front when password does not match with confirm password but its not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i want to match the current password with the confirm password but through this procedure its  not matching the passowrd kindly help me in this regard.

**ALL VALIDATION HERE (Confirm Password Validation in is last )**

```
function SignUp() {
    
    const [toggleState,setToggleState]=useState(0);
   
    const navigate=useNavigate();
```

//these all are useState

```
    const [employee_id,set_employeeID]=useState("");
    const [system_id,set_systemID]=useState("");
    const [first_name,set_firstName]=useState("");
    const [last_name,set_lastName]=useState("");
    const [select_uni,set_university]=useState("");
    const [email,set_email]=useState("");
    const [password,set_password]=useState("");
    const [confirm_password,set_confirmPassword]=useState("");
```

// these useState are for error message to show on Span

```
    const [EmployeeError,set_EmployeeError]=useState(false);
    const [SystemIDerror,set_systemID_Error]=useState(false);
    const [fnameError,set_fnameError]=useState(false);
    const [lnameError,set_lnameError]=useState(false);
    const [universityError,set_universityError]=useState(false);
    const [emailError,set_emailError]=useState(false);
    const [passwordError,set_passwordError]=useState(false);
    const [confirmPassError,set_confirmPassError]=useState(false);
    


    const teachersignup = async (e) => {
        if(first_name && last_name && select_uni && email&& password && confirm_password!=null )
        {

       
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(
        employee_id,
        first_name,last_name,select_uni,email,password,confirm_password
      );
      let data = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/signup", {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          employee_id,
          first_name,
          last_name,
          select_uni,
          email,
          password,
        }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      });

      const result = await data.json();
      console.log(result);

    }
    else{
        Dialog("Please Fill all the field");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    };




    const studentsignup=(e)=>{
                 e.preventDefault();
                 console.log(system_id,first_name,last_name,select_uni,email,password,confirm_password);
        }
```

// this is the system handler function

```
        const systemID_Handler=(e)=>{
            let item=e.target.value;
            
            
            if(item.match("^[1-9]{5}")!=null)
            {
                set_systemID_Error(false);
                set_systemID(item);
              
                
            }
            else
            {
            set_systemID_Error(true);
            }
          
        }
```

//Employee Handler

```
        const employeeid_Handler=(e)=>{
            let item=e.target.value;
            
            
            if(item.match("^[1-9]{5}")!=null)
            {
                set_EmployeeError(false);
                set_employeeID(item);
              
                
            }
            else
            {
            set_EmployeeError(true);
            }
          
        }
        const firstname_Handler=(e)=>{
            let item=e.target.value;
            
            if(item.match("[a-zA-Z]")!=null)
            {
                set_fnameError(false);
                set_firstName(item);
            }
            else
            {
                set_fnameError(true);
            }
            
            
        }
        const lastname_Handler=(e)=>{
            let item=e.target.value;
            
            if(item.match("[a-zA-Z]")!=null)
            {
                set_lnameError(false);
                set_lastName(item);
                
            }
            else
            {
                set_lnameError(true);
            }
           
          
        }
        const university_Handler=(e)=>{
            let item=e.target.value;

            console.log(item)
            if(item.match("[a-zA-Z]")!=null)
            {
                set_universityError(false);
            
                set_university(item);
                
            }
            else
            {
                set_universityError(true);
            }
         
        }
        const email_Handler=(e)=>{
            let item=e.target.value;
            
            if(item.match("[a-zA-Z]@numl.edu.pk")!=null)
            {
                set_emailError(false);
                set_email(item)
            }
            else
            {
                set_emailError(true);
            }
            
          
        }
```

//password handler function

```
        const password_Handler=(e)=>{
            // var passwordCheck=e.target.value;
            let  passwordCheck=e.target.value;
              
                let pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})"
                
                if(passwordCheck.match(pattern)!=null)
                {
                    set_passwordError(false);
                    set_password(passwordCheck);
                }
                else
                {
                    set_passwordError(true);
                }
               
            
             
           
          
        }
```

// confirm password handler

```
        const confirmPass_handler=(e)=>{
            let item=e.target.value;
            
                if(item.passwordCheck !== item)
                {
                    set_confirmPassError(false);
                    set_confirmPassword(item);
                
                    
                  
                }
                else
                {
                    set_confirmPassError(true);
                }
               
        }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
                                    <div className="  mb-2">
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        className="form-control block w-full px-4 py-2 text-base  font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
                                        placeholder="Password"
                                        autoComplete="new-password"
                                            id="password"
                                        onChange={password_Handler}
                                        
                                    />
                                    {passwordError? <span className="text-red-600 ">Enter Valid Password(Must use First letter capital and  any special character</span>:null}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className=" mb-2">
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        id="confirm_password"
                                        className="form-control block w-full px-4 py-2 text-base  font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
                                        placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                        autoComplete="new-password"
                                     
                                        onChange={confirmPass_handler}
                                       
                                    />
                                    {confirmPassError? <span className="text-red-600 ">Password not matched</span>:null}
                                    </div>
```

Comment: What is this trying to do? `let item=e.target.value; if(item.passwordCheck !== item)`. Seems unlikely that condition would ever be true.

Comment: i did this too  let item=e.target.value;   if(item.passwordCheck == item) but its not working too

Comment: You're expecting `e.target.value.passwordCheck` to equal `e.target.value`? Why would the value of the input--a string--have a "passwordCheck" property? Any why would `value.passwordCheck` be the same as `value`?

Comment: actually thats the point i am not  understanding that what should i do to match the input when user some string. For this i do item.passwordCheck == item but it doesnt work thats why i am here so some one can solve this

Comment: When the user types in the password confirmation field, confirmPass_handler gets called with an event (e). `e.target` is the input. `e.target.value` is what the user entered. You're assigning `item=e.target.value` and then comparing `item.passwordCheck !== item`, which is the equivalent of comparing `e.target.value.passwordCheck !== e.target.value`. You're checking a nonexistent property on the string the user entered to the string the user entered, and that's obviously not going to work.

Comment: @rayhatfield then what should i do for this so it get matched

Comment: This seems self evident, but compare it to the value of the password field instead.

Comment: @rayhatfield thank you now password and  confirm password matched